# C++ Loop Through a double value

Tags: c++

I need to loop through a double value, please see code below:

```
double impactTime = 3.43;
for(double d = impactTime - 1; d <= 0; d--)
{
    cout << "Now d is " << d;
}
```

But when I ran the program, the for loop does not run and It did not have error message, neither. The variable d is always null. I am new to C++, not sure how to make this work. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

Not surprising.  You start with d=2.43, and tell the program to repeat *while* it is lesser than or equal to 0.  So you never repeat.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your loop does not run is this condition:
d<=0.
d is initialized to 2.43. The first condition it checks to enter the loop is d<=0. Obviously,2.43 is not less than 0. So it never enters the loop.

Hope that helps.